# Is あらまあ linked to Malay "alamak", and which came first?

Tags: etymology, false-etymology, false-cognates

A [popular theory](https://says.com/my/lifestyle/did-you-know-that-the-japanese-also-use-the-malay-expression-alamak) claims that that the Japanese expression あらまあ is directly related to the Malay *alamak* (pronounced more or less identically, since the "k" is just a glottal stop), with speculation about which one came first and how it was imported (Malay traders in Japan, Japanese soldiers in Malaya during WW2, etc).

**Is there a known etymology in Japanese, and/or evidence of use before the 1940s?**

My uninformed opinion: あらまあ sounds to me like a portmanteau of あらあら and まあまあ, which are similar expressions of condolences/sympathy.

Comment: I think you're right, honestly. This 'alamak/あらまあ' connection sounds just as dubious as 'obrigado/ありがとう'.

Comment: Also "ach so/あっそう", "係/はい", "أنت/あんた" as far as I've heard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the entry of [精選版日本国語大辞典](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%BE%E3%81%82-428056):

> ※闇桜（1892）〈樋口一葉〉「あらマア何(どう)しませうねへ」

So the word form is attested at least since late 19th century.

As you said, this is a combination of あら + まあ. [あら](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89-427730) can be traced back to the 10th century and [まあ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%82-632683) to the 18th century with basically the same meaning as in today (interjection of amazement).

> ※落窪（１０Ｃ後）一「あらことごとし」
>
> ※洒落本・妓者呼子鳥（1777）四「そりゃアマアほんの事かへ」

Thus it should be natural to assume that it has developed independently from the Malay phrase, and their resemblance is a coincidence. Of course, one can argue that the either side of people learned the specific word used in the other and mimicked the phrase by a novel combination of native components, but that would be difficult to prove or disprove.

Answer (score 2):

The ["popular theory" linked from the question](https://says.com/my/lifestyle/did-you-know-that-the-japanese-also-use-the-malay-expression-alamak) suggests both that the Japanese expression may have come from the Malay, or that the Malay expression may have come from from the Japanese.

## The Japanese あらまあ (*ara mā*)

[Broccoli's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76645/is-%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%BE%E3%81%82-linked-to-malay-alamak-and-which-came-first#answer-76646) covers the Japanese.  In short: あらまあ is purely Japanese, composed of purely Japanese elements and formulated in a purely Japanese word-formation pattern.  Any influence from Malay is vanishingly unlikely.

## The Malay *alamak*

For this to come from Japanese, we have to ask, "where did that final //-k// come from?"

There is no apparent mechanism for this: there is no //-k// in the Japanese, nor is there any likely longer Japanese phrase where a following word after あらまあ might start with a //k-//, since this Japanese expression is phonologically a standalone.  So a borrowing appears to be ruled out purely on phonological grounds.

An internal Malay derivation may make more sense.

As described [over at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alamak), this is probably a combination of *Allah* ("Allah, God") + *mak* ("mother"), an expression of surprise, in similar fashion to Spanish *madre de Dios*, Dutch *moeder van God*, or Arabic أُمُّ اللهِ‎ (*ʾummu llāhi*).

Comment: +1, but as noted earlier, it's more a glottal stop than a /k/.  I'd render the Malay in Japanese as アラマッ, which is phonologically possible.

Comment: @lambshaanxy: More feasible, but still unlikely, given too that the JA term is most often rendered with a trailing vowel, 「まぁ...」rather than a truncated stop.  :)